# If validation condition is met, then run main chat code after clicking button

Tags: jquery, signalr

How can I make the main chat code **only** run if validation is passed (i.e. fields do not contain default values or are empty) after the user clicks on the sendMessage button?

Right now the main chat code runs anyway whether validation is passed or not.

```
// main chat code

$(function () {

    var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub;

    IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
    };

    $("#sendMessage").click(function () {
        IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
    });

    $.connection.hub.start();
});

// handling default values and validation

$(function () {
    $('#ideaTitle, #ideaBody').each(function () {
        $.data(this, 'default', this.value);
    }).focus(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'edited')) {
            this.value = "";
        }
    }).change(function () {
        $.data(this, 'edited', this.value != "");
    }).blur(function () {
        if (!$.data(this, 'edited')) {
            this.value = $.data(this, 'default');
        }
    });
    $('#sendMessage').click(function () {
        $('#ideaTitle,#ideaBody').each(function () {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()).length === 0) {
                alert('empty');
                return false;
            }
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) === $(this).data('default')) {
                alert('default');
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use only one $("#sendMessage").click

```
// main chat code

$(function () {

var IWannaChat = $.connection.myChatHub;

IWannaChat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
    $('#listMessages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
};

$("#sendMessage").click(function () {
        if ($.trim($("#ideaBody").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('empty');
            return false;
        }
        if ($.trim($("#ideaBody").val()) === $("#ideaBody").data('default')) {
            alert('default');
            return false;
        }
        else{
            IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
        }        
});

$.connection.hub.start();
});

// handling default values and validation

$(function () {
$('#ideaTitle, #ideaBody').each(function () {
    $.data(this, 'default', this.value);
}).focus(function () {
    if (!$.data(this, 'edited')) {
        this.value = "";
    }
}).change(function () {
    $.data(this, 'edited', this.value != "");
}).blur(function () {
    if (!$.data(this, 'edited')) {
        this.value = $.data(this, 'default');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This should do it, fix up the if statements in the `$("#sendMessage").click` function though.  Like this `$("#sendMessage").click(function () {
        if ($.trim($("#ideaBody").val()).length === 0) {
            alert('empty');
            return false;
        } else if ($.trim($("#ideaBody").val()) === $("#ideaBody").data('default')) {
            alert('default');
            return false;
        } else{
            IWannaChat.server.send($('#ideaBody').val());
        }        
});`